# pjsua2 android connection issues when internet disconected and connected

Tags: android, pjsip

I am developing android application using pjsua2.I am able to register,make calls and perform everything when there is internet connection but once the internet connection is lost and again connected to internet the connection is not established with the server. when I checked the logs it displayed Sip is not registered. even after internet connection is re-established.
Please some help to find what the mistake mght be ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use this piece of code
as described in this [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/2041)

```
IpChangeParam changeParam = new IpChangeParam();
endpoint.handleIpChange(changeParam);
```

Comment: hey can you tell me where to add this code piece in receiver or in the method where the initial registration is done?

Comment: You have to add this code in the receiver where you will listen for connection changes. @AnjaniMittal

Comment: and when do I have to call this? upon disconnection or associated or associating?

Comment: You have to call this every time your connection is changed. As you can see in the class / method name, it says IPChange. Means everytime your ip changes, you need to do this.
It can be 
   1. mobile data -> wifi
   2. wifi -> wifi
   3. wifi -> mobile data
   4. wifi / mobile data -> no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I found the same behavior when running in connection issues. I've ended registering to the `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` to detect when internet status is changed and then using a method to detect the new status.Bellow is my implementation for the method:

```
public enum InternetStatus { WIFI, MOBILE, ROAMING, NO_INTERNET, UNKNOWN };

/**
 * Get the internet status of the phone. The possible values are :
 *      +Not connected
 *      +Connected through WiFi
 *      +Connected to Mobile Carrier
 *      +Connected on Roaming
 * @param context Context under which the app is running
 * @return Returns the internet status as an enum value
 */
public static InternetStatus getInternetStatus(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

            // connected to wifi
            //Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return InternetStatus.WIFI;
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            if(activeNetwork.isRoaming()) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName() + " Roaming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // roaming
                return InternetStatus.ROAMING;
            }
            else {
                //Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName() + " NOT Roaming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return InternetStatus.MOBILE;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
        //Toast.makeText(context," NO Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return InternetStatus.NO_INTERNET;
    }

    return InternetStatus.UNKNOWN;
}
```

Once you get the internet connection you should access you SIP Account class and call

```
   sipAccount.setRegistration(true);
```

This will trigger the library to send the registration message once again and everything should work properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did the same thing. This works if you're not in a call. If you are in a call this doesn't work that means call doesn't reconnect. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.